# instance variable in class method

Tags: ruby

What does that @ notation in class method means in ruby?

```
class A
  def self.method1
    @variable
  end 
end
```

In the above example, @variable is equivalent to @@variable?

Answer (score 0):

> @variable is equivalent to @@variable?

No `@variable` is class instance variable of class `A`. Where as `@@variable` is a class variable of `A`.

```
class A
  def self.method1
    @variable = 10
  end 
end
A.method1
A.class_variables # => []
A.instance_variables # => [:@variable]
```